# _placeholderLabel.textColor not working in swift 5 Key Path

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have a design where I have a dark grey UItextfield so I want my placeholder to have white color instead of default color.

I am trying to achieve this using _placeholderLabel.textColor but it's not working I've googled and double checked the solution everything is as it should be but the placeholder's color is not changing

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You should set the text field's `.attributedPlaceholder` property...

```
    let placeHolderAttribString = NSAttributedString(
        string: "Placeholder",
        attributes: [
            .foregroundColor : UIColor.white,
        ])
    
    textField.attributedPlaceholder = placeHolderAttribString
```

no need to mess around with (unsupported) `_placeholderLabel.textColor` key path.

Comment: Actually it worked for me. In swift 4 or above all you all you have to do is that just write placeholderLabel.textColor instead of _placeholderLabel.textColor because the property with underscore was supported by swift below 4.0.

Comment: @MuazHassan - well, that demonstrates one of the reasons **not** to use undocumented / unsupported code. UIKit provides `.attributedPlaceholder` for exactly what you want to do. I would strongly recommend using that.